# Where is the startup file stored?

Tags: blend-files, installation

I need to reinstall Blender but I want to backup my startup file first. Where is this data stored?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When uninstalling (on Windows at least), you don't need to worry about this, Blender will ask you if you want to keep or remove your config files etc, simply choose the former and after reinstalling, your settings will still be there.

[image]

Additionally, if you uninstall and the version you are installing is different from the last, press *Copy Previous Settings* and it will apply your stored config to your fresh install after which you can save as your new default with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: This is the [wiki page](http://www.blender.org/manual/getting_started/installing_blender/directorylayout.html) for where things are stored in the different OSs

Comment: Blender recently became available on Steam, so I've opted to use that version. This answer was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 35):

The configuration files are:

**[startup.blend](https://www.blender.org/manual/preferences/introduction.html#startup-file)** and **userpref.blend**, bookmarks.txt, recent-files.txt,

#### Windows

The following files are stored in:

```
%APPDATA%\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.73\config
```

(`%APPDATA%` points to `C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Roaming`)

In more recent versions of Windows it will be in:

```
C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\<VersionNumber>\config
```

Note that AppData is a hidden folder, you can change directory to AppData from the command line.

#### Linux

The Linux versions stores the same files at this path

```
/home/<UserName>/.config/blender/2.73/config
```

#### OS X

For OS X, the config files can be located at

```
/Users/<UserName>/Library/Application Support/Blender/2.73/config
```

The Library folder is also likely to be hidden by default so you may have to look up how to unhide it.

More info: https://www.blender.org/manual/en/getting_started/installing/configuration/directories.html

Comment: A shortcut to Appdata is to type %appdata% into any folder's address bar.

Comment: That is the most likely place - [full path details can be found here](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Introduction/Installing_Blender/DirectoryLayout)

Comment: Changed the `C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Roaming` to `%APPDATA%` to help others. I hope that's ok.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know where it is stored, but you could just save your startup file as a normal .blend file, open it in the new blender installation and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> to set this file as your new startup file.

Comment: Since about 2.60 the startup is now in two files - `startup.blend` and `userpref.blend` this will save the main scene file but not the preference settings.