# Startup file not found in config folder

Tags: installation

I am looking for startup.blend file on linux debian. As explained http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Introduction/Installing_Blender/DirectoryLayout, it should be under config folder. but I did not find it. Any help?

Comment: This is a hidden folder in linux (there is a dot before the folders name). Try to press CTRL + H to unhide all hidden folders in your user directory.

Comment: The path is /home/your_user/.config/blender/version_number/config/startup.blend

Comment: @cegaton, it did not exist. I have used ls -a to show all files evec the hidden ones but it did not work.

Comment: Do you can see the hidden files and folders now?

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23338/where-is-the-startup-file-stored

Comment: @startingBlender How did you install blender? If you downloaded the bzip and extracted it somewhere, it might be in `~/place/where/you/extracted/it/2.74/config/` or something like that