# Saving user preferences per project

Tags: customization

I thought it had been asked already, but I searched, couldn't find anything for Version 2.74.

Is there a way to save user preferences, like hotkeys or enabled addons, into my .blend file? I may need specific keyboard shortcuts for a certain project, so I want to save the preferences so they would load ONLY for this project when I open it, and when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> - it would load the default startup settings.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do that is by manipulating with startup.blend's.

(*I feel Python solution probably should be somewhere here... Also this way is a little bit strange because of dealing with multiple config files*)

1. I save user settings so the main `startup.blend` (default one) looks
   like this:

   [image: startup_1]
2. In this `.blend` which will be the startup for the main
   project, continue setting up new preferences. Change Grid color in `3D View` so it differs from default settings, activate some addons etc. I also dropped default lamp and made deselecting everything to happen on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, so the `startup-for-CurrentProject.blend` looks like this:

   [image: startup_2]

   Create backup of the main `startup.blend` (renaming it to
   `startup_Main.blend`), save User Preferences in the opened `.blend`.
   Open file browser, find there new generated `startup.blend` ([how to find Blender's config file](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/23341/1245)), cut it
   from there and paste in work folder. Also rename this one in
   something user-friendly, like `startup-for-CurrentProject.blend`
   (for ease). Now, you'll be opening `CurrentProject.blend` using this
   file. Also, make sure to rename the main `startup_Main.blend` back
   to `startup.blend` so Blender to find exactly this one, not
   something else.
3. Without closing Blender continue creating something or open `.blend` which will be the main project, I call it `CurrentProject.blend`. I added something so
   it to differ from that bunch of startups. Saved it.

   [image: startup_3]
4. Now if creating / opening `blend` (or reloading default one by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>), you'l see that default user preferences remained unchanged.
5. To work on your project now you should open work folder and that
       `startup-for-CurrentProject.blend` you've saved earlier. Press
       <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> to open saved project using these
       settings. Find `CurrentProject.blend` and load it.

   [image]

   New settings were saved including enabled addons and keyboard
   shorcuts.

   Now, you have two `.blends` in work folder -
   `startup-for-CurrentProject.blend` and `CurrentProject.blend`.