# Rotating 3D view doesn't work in Sculpt mode

Tags: customization

I have my preferences set to rotate view in 3D Viewport using the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd>.

This is what I am used to using in other programs and works great in Blender in Object or Edit Mode.

When in Sculpt Mode I can not rotate the view using the mouse+key combo. However in Sculpt Mode I can rotate using the <kbd>Numpad 4</kbd>, <kbd>Numpad 6</kbd>, <kbd>Numpad 8</kbd> or <kbd>Numpad 3</kbd>.

I have looked for the setting to change in Preferences and answers online with no luck. Anyone know where to change the preferences for rotate view in different modes? Is that the problem?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It works for me in all the interaction modes after changing "Rotate View" option in "3D View - Global" entry. Try restoring this shortcut back (there should be [arrow to the right from top row](https://www.blender.org/manual/fr/preferences/input.html#keymap-editor) which allows restoring key map item) and then again set it up as you'd like. Or reset user prefs just to see if something else affects there.

Comment: Thanks and I tried that with the current file and it did not work. I did some tests and it seems like it is just the file that is causing the issue. A new blender file rotates using my preferences and the default preferences in Sculpt Mode. I guess the file is the problem?

Comment: Not that I'm sure because any .blend uses those preferences in Blender's folder (there's kind of another way with setting up [multiple](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32475/saving-user-preferences-per-project) configs but it's way too messy and I don't think you used that). This could be either bug or something with preferences indeed in that file. Did you try resetting all the prefs within it ? It's the most brutal way and it should've worked.

Comment: One more thing to try is to open that file within Blender with `Ctrl`+`O` and [uncheck *Load UI*](https://www.blender.org/manual/data_system/files/open.html#options) in the bottom left.

Comment: Tried to restore all prefs to blender defaults and that did not work. Also tried to open and uncheck the "Load UI". It is strange and I have also tried to remove everything (all objects) including cameras and lights and then adding a basic mesh, setting multi-res on it and then trying to rotate view in Sculpt but it doesnt work with this file. Also the pan or move mouse+key command does not work either. Let me know if I can send this file somewhere to be checked. Thanks Mr Zak for your help and suggestions.

Comment: It may be not good idea to send tthis very file because as I've got it you can't reproduce this problem once more. Anyway make sure final version of Blender is used and try to reproduce this behaviour in default file. Any bugs should be [reported accordingly](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/best-place-to-put-bug-reports) so if you can make that error once more it's a way to go.

Comment: Having the same problem! Camera rotation doesn't work in Sculpt mode. Anyone ever found a solution?