# MSI Installation issues

Tags: installation

I am trying to help a friend who uses this program,  The issue she is having is trying to install 2.76.  It gives her a message she has an older version already installed. She then uninstalled the older versions but now when she tries to install the only version that will install is version 2.74 which is an executable. When she tries to install version 2.75 it tells her there is a newer version installed. When she tries to install 2.75a or 2.76 it tells her there is an older version installed. Any help would greatly be appreciated.
Thanks
Mark

Comment: I installed over an existing older version in Windows before and had no trouble with it. The shortcut will update to the latest installed version anyway.

Comment: I never got that message on Windows 7 here. Latest install was 2.76 RC3

Comment: try the .zip version, that requires no install.

Comment: She has done the unzip version and is able to get it running, but she still wants to resolve the issue so she can get to the root of the problem. Is there a registry Key entry that would cause this issue?

Comment: This is indeed unusual. Delete the startup.blend and userpref.blend (see: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/23341/1853 ) Then uninstall all older versions using the "programs and features" Uninstall procedures.  And install the latest version.

Comment: I will have her try that , are the startup.blend and the  userpref.blend in the registry?

Comment: Ok I see they are hidden files, but I believe she had deleted all hidden files also but I will ask her. Thanks for your help Ill let you know how things are going.

Comment: She actually did this a couple of times and the problem still remains. She also rebooted after deleting files and the programs. Any more ideas?