# Where to find Blender's Prefs/Settings files in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: customization

First off, I did notice there's a similar thread. However, I needed to add that my files have a date for last year (?!). Really odd, I'd think, because I've been using Blender just couple days ago. Isn't the date of those files supposed to be updated every time I use Blender?

Btw, using the graphical Files Manager app, I found 3 files here:
 Home/.config/blender/2.77/config/
1. bookmarks.txt, 2. recent-files.txt, 3. userpref.blend

I need to install Blender in another pc soon. But it would be great to save the time needed to setting up Blender.

Thanks guys,

JDL

Comment: The file you need is **userpref.blend** http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23338/where-is-the-startup-file-stored

Comment: Thanks. Even if it dates back to last year?