# Blender wont work and just stays white window

Tags: audio, windows

I have been at this for hours and have not found a solution. Manually switched sound settings to 44100hz and then doesn't show that error but still opens and just stays all white window. I have checked my opengl and is on 4.4. I have tried older versions still same issue. I have copy and pasted opengl32 into the blender foundation folder. Tried -noaudio same issue. Im trying out Blender to learn animations and still have not been able to begin to learn. I hope it is not a sign that it is not something for me. Thank you so much for helping me.[image]

Comment: Looks like it is not initializing properly. Do any other versions work? If so report it as a bug. Also, that is black not white :)

Comment: Possible duplicate (Search is your friend) https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77857/error-al-lib-updatedeviceparams-failed-to-set-44100hz-got-48000hz-instead-wh/77896

Comment: Does the program open after that warning? Does it continue hanging on without loading up the interface? Please clarify "still opens and just stays all white window". Maybe related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61765/latest-version-of-blender-opens-with-blank-screen

Comment: I have also this message since I use USB headset, but Blender works properly. Only with different sound setting than default. I don't thing this is a problem. I thing the problem is what happen after - with no error message.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried uninstalling Blender and removing *all* config files?
They're found in %appdata%\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender*version number*\config.
I had your same problem and solved it by uninstalling and removing that folder, then reinstalling. Let me know!