# I can't open my User Prefs -- get and X on the icon

Tags: add-on, customization

I just activated some add ons that came with Blender -- and now I can't open the User Prefs any more. The User Prefs Icon has an X on it.

I'm on a Macbook air and am using Blender ver 2.79b 2018-03-22 -- I am also using a reg 3 button mouse.

Everything seemed to work fine until I activated the modeling add ons and a couple others like ant.

Do I need to uninstall Blender and re-install and how do I prevent this from happening again with add ons?

Thank you.

Comment: Just delete the user preferences files, or do file>**Load Factory Settings** in the main menu.

Comment: I tried Load Factory Settings and that did not fix the problem.   Where do I delete the user pref files?  The specific add ons I just added?  I'm not clear on this because User Prefs worked fine before I did the add ons.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23338/where-is-the-startup-file-stored the file to delete is userpref.blend

Comment: If I delete userprefs.blend, am I totally deleting the user prefs from blender?  Why would I do that when it worked up until the add ons -- and if I need to tweak something, unless it locks up again, I would not be able to adjust any user prefs unless this is an issue when changing anything in user prefs on Mac OS.  I've used Blender before on a PC with Win7-- but not on a Mac until now.

Comment: I spoke to soon -- it seem resetting the factory setting worked -- i can access user prefs again.   Thank you.   Now I'll figure out which add on is the culprit or if they all are.   Thanks again!!!

Comment: blender creates a new clean preferences file when you delete the existing one. It is another form of "factroy reset"

Comment: Please write an answer to your own question. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer