# How do i copy my user preferences settings and load them into an older version of blender?

Tags: interface, export, blend-files

Is there a way to copy blender config (user preferences settings) from blender 2.82 to 2.81 version? My blender keeps crashing randomly and i think switching to the stable version is my only option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can copy the files with the preferences and default project to the folder of other version of blender. The files are called **userpref.blend** and **startup.blend** (there are also files for bookmarks.txt, and recent-files.tx)

For the location of those files in your particluar operating system refer to:

[Where is the startup file stored?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23338/where-is-the-startup-file-stored)