# How do I Backup my User Preferences File?

Tags: startup-file

Blender 2.83 crashed because I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>  one too many times (this pitfall is still a thing. At this late stage. Yes). Now one of my more recent User Preferences hotkey changes is reverted to the default. Maybe more have reverted also, but I don't yet know the extent of this annoyance.

I know better than to expect to enjoy a crash-free Blender experience. But at the very least, I want to enjoy a shortcut losing-free experience. So I want to know how to prevent the need to manually rebuild these shortcuts. I know there is a User Preference file somewhere that could probably be re-loaded, provided I had a backed up version located somewhere else. I would create one, if I knew where the User Preference file is stored. But I don't. I don't even know what the exact file I'm needing is called. I'm running Ubuntu Studio 19.10, and I don't know where to look for this file.

Comment: the file you need is the **usrepref.blend** file. Remember to use the search box at the top of the page for common questions. [Where is the startup file stored?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23338/where-is-the-startup-file-stored)

Comment: Hi. Please try to use existing tags when creating a question. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do i copy my user preferences settings and load them into an older version of blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/164404/how-do-i-copy-my-user-preferences-settings-and-load-them-into-an-older-version-o)

Comment: Hi, susu. I don't appreciate you assuming I didn't search for questions before asking a question. Because that absolutely didn't happen. At all. I searched for some time, in fact. But thanks for adding something helpful in addition to your admonishment.

Comment: Hi, Ray. I would like to know why it's possible to create tags if we are only going to be discouraged from using them afterwards? Especially when they make sense, and ought to already exist.

Comment: Hello :). You can backup and sync your settings using the free [Blender Cloud addon](https://cloud.blender.org/services). It also backs up your startup file, which is nice.

Comment: I don't know why it's so easy to create tags. I personally don't think it should be. In general, I would suggest asking a question on the [meta] if you want to suggest a new tag.

Comment: So, it is your opinion that tags should not be so easy to create. And yet you seem to believe it is I who should go to Meta to suggest changes to the way the site is structured. Perhaps going to Meta something you should consider yourself also, if you don't like how tags already work. Rather than urging people not to create them, as if they have violated an established norm in doing so. This kind of approach is liable to create both confusion and conflict.

Comment: Except for [T77774](https://developer.blender.org/T77774) there is no confirmed bug report for undo that affects Blender 2.83. Please read [this guide](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/173685/74827) and post a bug report on the bug tracker.

Comment: I humbly apologize,