# Can I recover my old keymap without opening Blender?

Tags: shortcut

After my Graphics Card broke I want to use Blender 2.79 on a new PC. Unfortunately I cannot open Blender without a Graphics Card to export my Keymap (and other Settings, like Design). Can I get these Settings without installing the Graphics Card back and forth?

Comment: I believe you want to locate and copy your user pref file. Its file path is different depending on your platform.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need is to copy the **userprefs.blend** file from the old computer to the new one.

If you are using windows the file is usually in your user's app data roaming folder. For more. Info please refer to this post:

[Where is the startup file stored?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23338/where-is-the-startup-file-stored)