# Carrying UI Settings from Windows to Linux

Tags: customization, windows, linux, startup-file

I'm trying out Linux (Kubuntu 20.04), moving from Windows 7, just to see how I feel about it. I installed Blender 2.83 and I'm having trouble opening up the start up file I have saved away with the settings I like. I can open it up, but the settings that I had are not taking effect at all. There are some special tweaks in there too, as I was indoctrinated into the 3D world through 3DS Max, and my Blender UI setup reflects that. Am I going to have to just go through and make changes all over again? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the **startup.blend** and **userprefs.blend** from the old computer to the new one.

For the location of the prefs file read:

[Where is the startup file stored?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23338/where-is-the-startup-file-stored)

Also on the windows version export your keyboard configuration and load it on the linux box.

Lastly, make sure that all of the addons you were using in the default setup are available and installed on the new box as well.

Comment: That worked. Thanks!

Comment: on my end my linux instance does not have .config folder in user or home ect... not sure where the preferences are stored when i just extracted blender. odd we can't pick a location or open the used location to grab or paste the prefs file..