# problem opening files after moving them to a different folder

Tags: osx, file-browser

I moved around some of my blender files by putting them in a new folder ("failed tests") and now blender seems unable to navigate to any new files in the initial open file screen. I can open a file it has on the recent files list, but when I go to "open.." to navigate to another file, the file browser that opens up there won't let me click on any files other than whatever file I've opened last. If I go into the place where I can write the file path I can tell it to get to a specific file, but even then it's having problems with those files: it won't select anything in object mode. Any ideas what on earth is happening? I reinstalled Blender but the same thing is going on...

Edited to add: I can use the file path to get where I want to go, but I'd rather be able to double click on files in the file browser window: any idea why I can't?
[image: file browser]

Comment: Okay. After much fussing and reinstalling I deleted my user preferences and that fixed everything...

Comment: Sure, happy to. I'm on a mac. First I followed the instructions to show the hidden files on my hard drive like the ones on this link: (https://setapp.com/how-to/show-hidden-files-on-mac#:~:text=See%20hidden%20files%20on%20Mac%20via%20Finder&text=In%20Finder%2C%20open%20up%20your,2%20to%20hide%20them%20again!) . After that I went to my hard drive, then users/(my username)/ Library/ Application Support/ Blender/ 2.82/ config/ and then I dragged the preferences file to the trash and emptied it. I restarted Blender after that and everything works fine now.

Answer (score 2):

There is a file called ***recent-files.txt*** that is saved where the config files are.
If you edit that with the new paths you should be fine.

For the location of the file refer to this post:

[Where is the startup file stored?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23338/where-is-the-startup-file-stored)

Comment: Thank you. That seems to reflect the recent files, which is good, but what's odd is that I can't double click on any folders to open them in the file browser... Any idea why that's happening

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I'm on a mac. First I followed these instructions to show the hidden files on my hard drive: in Finder, open up your Macintosh HD folder. Press Command+Shift+Dot. Your hidden files will become visible.  After that I went to my hard drive, then users/(my username)/ Library/ Application Support/ Blender/ 2.82/ config/ and then I dragged the preferences file to the trash and emptied it. I restarted Blender after that and everything works fine now.