# How to bring back first start Key configure preset selection?

Tags: interface

If you first start Blender after installation you get a screen where you can select the key bind preset, between Industry standard, blender 2.79, Blender 2.8+ etc.

I Miss clicked there and now i cant figure out how to bring this window back.

Comment: Thank you, that did the job.

Answer (score 1):

On the top meny choose: *File* > *Defaults* > ***Load Factory Settings***.

Or delete the **[userpref.blend](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/blender_directory_layout.html?highlight=userpref)** file.

To find it, read this link:

[Where is the startup file stored?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23338/where-is-the-startup-file-stored)

or read the manual page:

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/blender_directory_layout.html?highlight=userpref