# How do I get Blender to refer to the last folder opened as the default for the File-Open dialog?

Tags: interface, file-browser

I am trying to figure out how to get Blender to default to the last used file location when opening a file.  As part of my pipeline for editing FBX files, I add diffuse, normal, metallic, specular, and roughness textures to each mesh, and every time I press *Open*, the dialog box defaults to the location of the .blend file I'm using. I know I can go to the lower left corner of the dialog box and select my target folder from the *Recent* list, but this is a pain when you're doing this dozens of times, and I'm hoping I can make Blender behave in a way that makes working with my pipeline more efficient.

How do I get Blender to refer to the last folder opened as the default for the File-Open dialog?

Comment: Maybe not the finest way, but it should work. Blender stores configuration files that are read when opened and written when closed. The location depends on the operating system. See answer from @stacker [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23338/where-is-the-startup-file-stored). In the config folder there is a file called `recent-files.txt`. The first entry inside controls which folder is used when opening the filebrowser. Move your favorite to the top and save the file. Now mark `recent-files.txt` as read-only via operating system, so Blender can not change anymore.